# Using DistilBERT for generating sentences of text

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

good day,
I have used the wonderful library huggingface transformers to generate text with GPT2 and this works great:

```
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Once upon a time there was")).unsqueeze(0)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2", pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
greedy_output = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=50)
print("Output:\n" + 100 * '-')
print(tokenizer.decode(greedy_output[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

My issue is that now I want to do the same but with the smaller simpler DistilmBERT model which is also multilingual in 104 languages, so I want to generate text in for example Spanish and English and with this lighter model

I have tried this

```
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-multilingual-cased')
model = DistilBertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-multilingual-cased')
input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute", add_special_tokens=True)).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
outputs = model(input_ids, masked_lm_labels=input_ids)
loss, prediction_scores = outputs[:2]
```

but Im not sure if this is the right model to use. And once I get the outputs, how would I get the continuation of the phrase from that?

After more tests, I can get the generation working well with distilgpt2, the thing is that I would like to do it multilingual using the light multilingual model DistilmBERT  (distilbert-base-multilingual-cased), any tips?

```
import torch
from transformers import *
from transformers import TFGPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Once upon a time")).unsqueeze(0)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("distilgpt2", pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
greedy_output = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=50) #greedy search

sample_outputs = model.generate(
    input_ids,
    do_sample=True, 
    max_length=50, 
    top_k=50, 
    top_p=0.95, 
    temperature=1,
    num_return_sequences=3
)

print("Output:\n" + 100 * '-')
for i, sample_output in enumerate(sample_outputs):
  print("{}: {}".format(i, tokenizer.decode(sample_output, skip_special_tokens=True)))`
```

thank you for your help :)

Comment: I am referring to Distilmbert, not Distilbert: 
Huggingface: "December 6, 2019 - Update We release DistilmBERT: 92% of bert-base-multilingual-cased on XNLI. The model supports 104 different languages listed here."

Answer (score 2):

I just copy the answer that [LysandreJik](https://github.com/LysandreJik) gave [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/4563)

> Unfortunately DistilmBERT can't be used for generation. This is due to
>   the way the original BERT models were pre-trained, using masked
>   language modeling (MLM). It therefore attends to both the left and
>   right contexts (tokens on the left and right of the token you're
>   trying to generate), while for generation the model only has access to
>   the left context.
>
> GPT-2 was trained with causal language modeling (CLM), which is why it
>   can generate such coherent sequences. We implement the generation
>   method only for CLM models, as MLM models do not generate anything
>   coherent.

In the documentation you can find models fitted to tasks.

A quick example in https://transformer.huggingface.co/

Comment: thank you very much, I understand. Unfortunately I didn't find so far a pretrained gpt-2 model in spanish, hopefully somebody will release one at some point, thank you again ;)